# Angular directives with a shared controller don't share the controller's $scope

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

**If I have two different directives with isolated scopes, and they share a controller, shouldn't they share the controller's `$scope`?**

---

Effectively, I have the following scenario:

1. I call to the server and pass it some parameters, let's call them `x` and `y`.
2. The server either returns some data, or it returns null which indicates that this data is not available.
3. If the data is returned, I need to display a button; if the user clicks the button, it will display the data in a separate div.
4. If the data is *not* returned, I do not display the button.

I've been trying to implement this as a set of linked directives. I'm trying to do it this way because this "component" is to be re-used multiple times in the application, and I'm trying to do this in two directives because I couldn't figure out any other way to make a single directive control two different elements.

In addition to there being many, they need to be linked by `x` and `y` values. So if I have a button with particular `x` and `y`, then clicking on it will only toggle the visibility of the display area with the same `x` and `y` values. Effectively a given view will have multiple of each with different `x` and `y` values.

Anyway, I have a potential working solution, but I seem to be having problems with the shared scope. When I click the button, I have logging statements which correctly show that we trigger the "show" logic. But the logging statements in the `ng-if` of the div consistently evaluate the same logic to false and doesn't display.

My solution is in three parts:

- A directive for the button
- A directive for the "display"
- A controller that is shared by the two

I have a trivial working example, which I will share below. There's a Plunkr URL at the end of this post as well.

Here is the HTML. The `<p>` tag in the middle is just to demonstrate that the two directives are physically not adjacent.

```
<trigger x="apple" y="2" ></trigger>
<p>Some unrelated dom content...</p>
<display x="apple" y="2"></display>
```

This is the `trigger` directive, which is the button:

```
app.directive("trigger", function() {
  return {
    restrict: "E",
    scope: {
      x : "@",
      y : "@"
    },
    transclude: false,
    template: "<button ng-if='hasCalculation(x,y)' ng-click='toggle()'>Trigger x={{x}} & y={{y}}</button>",
    controller: 'testController',
    link: function(scope) {
      scope.doSomeWork();
    }
  };
});
```

This is the `display` directive, which is supposed to show the data when toggled by the button:

```
app.directive("display", function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
      x : '@',
      y : '@'
    },
    require: '^trigger',
    transclude: false,
    controller: 'testController',
    template: "<p ng-if='shouldShow(x,y)'>{{getCalculation(x,y)}}</p>"
  };
});
```

This is the shared controller, `testController`:

```
app.controller("testController", ["$scope", function($scope) {
  $scope.shouldShow = [[]];
  $scope.calculatedWork = [[]];
  $scope.doSomeWork = function() {
    var workResult = "We called the server and calculated something asynchonously for x=" + $scope.x + " and y=" + $scope.y;
    if(!$scope.calculatedWork[$scope.x]) {
      $scope.calculatedWork[$scope.x] = [];
    }
    $scope.calculatedWork[$scope.x][$scope.y] = workResult;
  };

  $scope.hasCalculation = function(myX, myY) {
    var xRes = $scope.calculatedWork[myX];
    if(!xRes) {
      return false;
    }
    return $scope.calculatedWork[myX][myY]
  }

  $scope.toggle = function() {
    if(!$scope.shouldShow[$scope.x]) {
      $scope.shouldShow[$scope.x] = [];
    }
    $scope.shouldShow[$scope.x][$scope.y] = !$scope.shouldShow[$scope.x][$scope.y];
    console.debug("Showing? " + $scope.shouldShow[$scope.x][$scope.y]);
  }

  $scope.isVisible = function(myX, myY) {
    console.debug("Checking if we should show for " + myX + " and " + myY);

    var willShow;
    if(!$scope.shouldShow[myX]) {
      willShow = false;
    } else {
       willShow = $scope.shouldShow[myX][myY];
    }
    console.debug("Will we show? " + willShow);
    return willShow;
  }

  $scope.getCalculation = function(myX, myY) {
    if(!$scope.calculatedWork[myX]) {
      return null;
    }
    return $scope.calculatedWork[myX][myY];
  }
}]);
```

Here is the [Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/ac8kzz0GizR0HxLOGDBG?p=preview).

If you go to the Plunkr, you'll see the trigger button correctly rendered. If you click the button, you'll see that the `toggle()` method correctly flips the value of the `shouldShow` to the opposite of what it was previously (there's a console debug statement in that method that shows its result). You'll also see the re-evaluation of the `isVisible` method which determines if the display should show -- this *always* returns false.

I think it has to do with the fact that I'm saving my data and visibility state relative to `$scope`. My understanding of this is that each individual directive has its own `$scope`, but since they share a controller, shouldn't they share *that* controller's `$scope`?

Answer (score 0):

An isolate scope **does not** prototypically inherit the properties of the parent scope.

> In AngularJS, a child scope normally prototypically inherits from its parent scope. One exception to this rule is a directive that uses scope: { ... } -- this creates an "isolate" scope that does not prototypically inherit.（and directive with transclusion） This construct is often used when creating a "reusable component" directive. In directives, the parent scope is used directly by default, which means that whatever you change in your directive that comes from the parent scope will also change in the parent scope. If you set scope:true (instead of scope: { ... }), then prototypical inheritance will be used for that directive.

Source: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes

Additionally, a controller is not a singleton it is a class...so two directives can't share a controller. They each instantiate the controller.

If you want two controllers to share the same data, use a [factory](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/providers#factory-recipe).